# HTML not rendering well on Bootstrap Modal on Angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying to get a simple pop up on my project using this [shlomiassaf/angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal) library. But it just doesn't seem to render the html correctly.

This is the code for the modal I have so far (I tried to keep it as simple as possible):

```
    public addItinerary = () => {
        this.modal.alert()
            .size('lg')
            .showClose(true)
            .title('Add Itinerary')
            .body(`
            <h4>Please configure your new itinerary</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><input type='checkbox' checked />Dallas</li>
                <li><input type='checkbox' />Houston (Saving 0:45)</li>
                <li><input type='checkbox' checked />Brownsville</li>
                <li><input type='checkbox' checked />Laredo</li>
                <li><input type='checkbox' />La Enchilada (Saving 0:30)</li>
</ul>
            <b>Repeat On</b><br />
            <input type="checkbox"> Monday
            <input type="checkbox"> Tuesday
            <input type="checkbox"> Wednesday
            <input type="checkbox"> Thursday
            <input type="checkbox"> Friday
            <input type="checkbox"> Saturday
            <input type="checkbox"> Sunday
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select>
                        <option>Test Option</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5"></div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" /> All Year<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" /> All Day
                </div>
</div>`)
            .open();
    };
```

And this is the modal I am getting (notice how any checkbox and select controls):[image: Modal I am getting for the code above.]

Is there any problem with the way I am structuring my code? Do you know a simpler solution/library to get a modal on my angular 4 app?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think in this case you need to create a separate TS file with the content in the same way that it's done here: https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal/blob/master/src/demo/app/bootstrap-demo/bootstrap-demo-page/custom-modal-sample.ts

Answer (score 0):

BS may be kind of particular with their form fields. I noticed that they use the checkbox field like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
</div>
```

Right now your corresponding `checkbox` text is not wrapped in a `label` tag. Also not having the fields in a form tag may be cause issues as well. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I tried with this code (and others found at the bs docs) but still no luck.

Comment: @Multitut if you run the HTML code outside of the JS call do you see the form fields then?

Comment: hmm since your html code is captured in . body('...') perhaps you should replace your HTML single quotes with double quotes. Your first set of checkboxes have single quotes around them